# Remove One or More Blank Lines After a String

Tags: regex, awk, sed

```
#+BEGIN_HTML

some html
more html

#+END_HTML
```

I have some files that contain text like the above. I want to remove any blank lines following #+BEGIN_HTML, so I end up with:

```
#+BEGIN_HTML
some html
more html

#+END_HTML
```

The file contains blank lines in other places, which I don't want to remove. I am struggling to come up with a regexp that will let me do this.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I am used to using sed to work on a single line at a time, but have never tried to process multiple lines. Also discovered that I need to learn awk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed ':a;/^#+BEGIN_HTML/{N;/\n./!s/\n.*//;ta}' file
```

Create a label `a`. For lines that start with `#+BEGIN_HTML`, append the next line to pattern space. Substitute everything from newline to the end of next line unless it is not a line that is blank. Repeat the loop if the substitution modified the pattern space.

Comment: @jaypal i think  `perl -00pe` is better than `-0777pe`. Am i correct?

Comment: @jaypal: There was no error but it just didn't replace those blank lines. And yes it worked with gnu-sed so +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk '!NF && f {next} 1; NF {f=0} /#\+BEGIN_HTML/ {f=1}' file
#+BEGIN_HTML
some html
more html

#+END_HTML
```

Or as Jidder sugested:

```
awk '!NF&&f{next}{f=/#\+BEGIN_HTML/}1' file
```

Comment: Slight adjustment and it will work `awk 'NF{x=0}x{next}/#\+BEGIN_HTML/{x=1}1'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Fixed, even some shorter.

Comment: @Jotne your edit won't work either.You need the 1 at the end or semi colons.

Comment: @jotne also you can remove the ternary if completely `awk '!NF&&f{next}{f=/#\+BEGIN_HTML/}1'` and yours is shorter !

Comment: @Jidder Nice. My hat off for you. I was up your street, but my brain passed out some seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/#\+BEGIN_HTML/{print; skip=1; next} skip {if (!NF) next; else skip=0} 1' file
#+BEGIN_HTML
some html
more html

#+END_HTML
```

Comment: This will fail if follow `BEGIN_HTML` is non blank like.

Comment: Yes, `sed` is too cryptic (unreliable) for me, went back to friendly `awk` now :)

Comment: I think `sed` is best for this task, see my answer.

Comment: Yes I checked and your sed command doesn't work for me even when I used `gnu sed` only @Jaypal 's version worked but only when I used gnu-sed.

Comment: Yes I did, didn't work but and I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: You mean this `sed -e ':1' -e '/#+BEGIN_HTML/{$!N;/\n$/s///;t1}'` didn't work? Don't mind, I don't care about voting

Comment: Yes `sed -e ':1' -e '/#+BEGIN_HTML/{$!N;/\n$/s///;t1}'` doesn't work with OSX sed but works with gnu-sed

Answer (score 0):

Through perl,

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/(?<=^#\+BEGIN_HTML\n)\n+//g' file
#+BEGIN_HTML
some html
more html

#+END_HTML
```

**OR**

```
perl -00pe 's/(?<=^#\+BEGIN_HTML\n)\n+//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed -e ':1' -e '/#+BEGIN_HTML/{$!N;/\n$/s///;t1}'
```

Comment: @Gnouc sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Comment: @Gnouc I didn't down vote but you have my upvote for a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one using awk:

```
awk 'f{if(!NF)next;f=0}/#\+BEGIN_HTML/{f=1}1' file
```

`f` is set to 1 when the pattern is matched. When `f` is 1, blank lines (where `NF` is 0) are skipped. `f` is set to 0 when the line is no longer blank.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file
#+BEGIN_HTML



some html
more html

#+END_HTML
$ awk 'f{if(!NF)next;f=0}/#\+BEGIN_HTML/{f=1}1' file
#+BEGIN_HTML
some html
more html

#+END_HTML
```